How can I increase each group by N percent than the previous group?
First of all I'm not sure if it is the correct title. Feel free to suggest a better one.
This is my DataFrame:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [100, 100, 102, 102, 106, 106, 106, 107, 107, 107]
    }
)

And this is the expected output. I want to create column b:
     a    b
0  100    100  
1  100    100
2  102    103
3  102    103
4  106    106.09
5  106    106.09
6  106    106.09
7  110    110
8  110    110
9  110    110

The process is as follows:
a) Groups are defined by column a.
b) Each group must be AT LEAST 3 percent higher than the previous group. That is the output of column b.
For example:
First group is 100. So the process starts for the next group.
100 * 1.03 = 103
The next group is 102. It is less than 103. So for b, 103 is selected. Now the next group is 106 so:
103 * 1.03 = 106.09
106 is less than this number so 106.09 is selected. For the next group since 110 > 106.09 * 1.03, 110 is selected.
This is one of my attemps. But it feels like it is not the correct approach:
df['streak'] = df.a.ne(df.a.shift(1)).cumsum()
df['b'] = df.groupby('streak')['a'].apply(lambda x: x * 1.03)


how are you getting 100 in column b?

You  can try:
import pandas as pd


def get_b(a, perc=1.03):
    curr, prev_val = None, None

    for value in a:
        if curr is None:
            curr = value
        elif value != prev_val:
            curr = tmp if value < (tmp := curr * perc) else value
        prev_val = value

        yield curr


df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [100, 100, 102, 102, 106, 106, 106, 110, 110, 110]})
df["b"] = list(get_b(df["a"]))

print(df)

Prints:
     a       b
0  100  100.00
1  100  100.00
2  102  103.00
3  102  103.00
4  106  106.09
5  106  106.09
6  106  106.09
7  110  110.00
8  110  110.00
9  110  110.00

